# Pyspark UDF monitoring with prometheus

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I am am trying to monitor some logic in a udf using counters.

i.e.

```
counter = Counter(...).labels("value")

@ufd
def do_smthng(col):
  if col:
    counter.label("not_null").inc()
  else:
    counter.label("null").inc()
  return col
```

This is not the real case, but you should get the idea.
I have followed this article:
https://kb.databricks.com/metrics/spark-metrics.html

I have so far tried:

- Using a global prometheus counter (Failed with Lock is not picklable)
- Creating a custom source using py4j:

```
# noinspection PyPep8Naming
class CustomMetrics:
    def __init__(self, sourceName, metricRegistry):
        self.metricRegistry = metricRegistry
        self.sourceName = sourceName

    class Java:
        implements = ["org.apache.spark.metrics.source.Source"]

py_4j_gateway = spark_session.sparkContext._gateway
metric_registry = py_4j_gateway.jvm.com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry()
SparkEnv = py_4j_gateway.jvm.org.apache.spark.SparkEnv
custom_metrics_provider = CustomMetrics("spark.ingest.custom", metric_registry)
```

Which failed with the same error.
I also can't get `SparkEnv.get.metricsSystem` so I can't register the custom metrics client in any case.

Is there no way for me to access the internal metric registry from python?
I am starting to wonder how people do monitor spark pipelines with custom metrics.

Spark 3.1.2
Python 3.8 x86
MackBook Pro M1 Pro

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a [accumulator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#accumulators)? It's made to be accessible and is perfect for counting things.  It's a hold over from Map Reduce that was used for collecting metrics before spark was invented.

*EDIT* this does not get displayed in the spark UI.  It's clear the [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2868) is known but has been closed.  I'll leave the rest of the answer here for people that don't use python, but this does not display in the Spark UI. (Can be used for other things but not display in spark UI)

Your accumulator can then be exposed as a sink via a  ['PrometheusServlet'](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html)

> namespace=AccumulatorSource note: User-configurable sources to attach
> accumulators to metric system DoubleAccumulatorSource
> LongAccumulatorSource

Comment: So you suggest baking a counter into an accumulator or using the accumulator itself?

Comment: Accumulators are made for counting, I'd use it for counting.

Comment: So I'd still need to push the data to prometheus manually... NVM that is not what I want

Comment: well, accumulators are available to be monitored.... I updated my answer so it's more helpful.

Comment: Ah ok fair enough, I’ll try that!

Comment: @MattAndruff in pyspark there is no named accumulators , as per the spark documentation only long and double accumulators are allowed to send metrics right ? , the accumulator i have created is not showing in sparkui and metric as well

Comment: You are correct: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2868 the issue is closed but incomplete.